Bucket records into batches of a certain size in Snowflake
What would be the best way to bucket records into batches of a predefined size? I would like to tag each record with a batch/bucket number for further processing.
For example, let's say I have 1110 records and the batch/bucket size is 200, I should end up with either:

5 batches of 200 records, and one batch of 110 records.
6 batches of 185 records.

The background/context is for each batch to then be processed by an external service, which has a maximum allowed batch size (which varies per service).

I figured out a way to do it using the NTILE window functions:
WITH records AS (
  SELECT RANDOM() AS value
  FROM TABLE (generator(rowcount => 1110))
),
batches AS (
  SELECT
    value,
    NTILE(
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records)/200
    ) OVER (
      ORDER BY NULL
    ) AS batch
  FROM records
)
SELECT batch, COUNT(*)
FROM batches
GROUP BY ALL;

Result:


My first approach was to use ROW_NUMBER(), but there's a bit more overhead with that approach (although the result is the same):
WITH records AS (
  SELECT RANDOM() AS value
  FROM TABLE (generator(rowcount => 1110))
),
batches AS (
  SELECT
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY NULL
    ) AS rn,
    (rn % CEIL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records)/200)) AS batch
  FROM records
)
SELECT batch, COUNT(*)
FROM batches
GROUP BY ALL;

